# SAS resolve with data step in macro

Tags: sas, macros, sas-macro

I have one question and/or prompt.
I made and experimenting that code:

```
/* defined macro */
    %macro makro1(par1);
    %let i = 0;
        %IF &par1. = 1 %then %do; 35 %end;
        %ELSE %IF &par1. = 0 %then %do; 15 %end;
        %ELSE 12;

    %let i = %eval(&i. + 1);
    data _temp_temp&i.;
    _temp = &par1.;
    run;
    %mend makro1;

/* proc sql */
    Proc sql;
    Create table TESCIOR as
    Select
    a.*
    ,resolve('%makro1(' || put(licensed,1.) || ')') as new2
    ,resolve('%makro1(licensed)') as new3
    FROM work._PRODSAVAIL a
    ;quit;
```

How I can in resolve macro1 (in field new2) run date step "_temp_temp%i." in makro1, and iterate that variable &i. ?
I need do calculate in makro1 (which return in field new2) and create table _temp_temp.

Thank for help!

Comment: Are you trying to store the data step code your macro generates into your variables NEW2 and NEW3?  If not then you cannot use that macro in that way.

Comment: Currently that code write in field all procedure (number from IF and code data step). But I need set in field results from IF, and create table from data step.
I do not want write data step as string, but as procedure (create 8 tables, as records in prodsavail)

Comment: Unless you want to make something so complex no one will understand it pick one function for the macro. It either emits a number or it emits codes.  If it just emits the number then you could use it with RESOLVE() function.

Answer (score 1):

Your macro cannot work as written.  Main issue is that it is generating invalid SAS code because it is generating a number before the DATA statement. For example when PAR1=1 it generates this:

```
35 data _temp....
```

Secondary issue is that it is always generating dataset named `_TEMP_TEMP1` since it always sets `I` to 0 and then increments it once.

If you want to dynamically call a macro use CALL EXECUTE() function in a data step.

```
data _null_;
  set work._PRODSAVAIL ;
  call execute(cats('%nrstr(%makro1)(',licensed,')'));
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Macro Language Reference" documentation explains [`RESOLVE`](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p1ccfaw12wm8o3n1evurg9ov7dp6.htm&locale=en).

- Q: What does resolve do ?
- A: It returns the source code generated by the macro system for the passed expression.

`RESOLVE` does not execute the generated source code.  It will execute as much of the *macro instructions* as it can.  If the passed expression is expected to run a step boundary, `resolve` is the wrong feature to be using in your code.

The coding of

```
, resolve('%makro1(' || put(licensed,1.) || ')') as new2
, resolve('%makro1(licensed)') as new3
```

indicates you may be incorrectly mixing scopes; macro-time versus run-time versus run-time-dynamic.

Suppose your data set has 100 rows.  Do you really want to create 200 temp tables ?

Consider looking into `DOSUBL` if you feel a need to execute generated source code **during** proc step run-time.  Note: Generated source code could be a macro invocation that generates more source code, which will which will also be executed (in the separate synchronous `DOSUBL` submit stream).

My guess is there is a much simpler solution to what you are really attempting but did not describe in the question.

Comment: Hey, thanks for hint abount DOSUBL :) Generally I tried write code which and return value to field and execute code in macro - but as I see - that is not possible.